# MySQL - Get actual precision and scale of number

Tags: mysql-5.5, number-formatting, decimal

I would like to query the integer part and fractional part of all decimal(8,4) values in a column. By that I mean, I want to know the actual given values, and not the max allowed by the data type, which are integer = 4, fractional = 4.

For example, 33.99 would return (2,2) and 1.375 would return (1,3). I have started trying to parse the numbers as strings using char_length() like this:

```
SELECT max(char_length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'.',1))), max(char_length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'.',-1)));
```

A similar, more intuitive, and uglier way in Oracle is

```
SELECT max(length(regexp_substr(col,'^.*[.]',1))), max(length(regexp_substr(col,'[.].*$',1)))
```

But is there a better way that exploits MySQL's knowledge that these are **actually numbers**?

[This page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/precision-math-expressions.html) implies that the true lengths of numbers - e.g. without leading 0s - is known and retrievable, so I was hoping there was a function that would just do this. Does this have something to do with the assertion that ["MySQL returns all data as strings and expects you to convert it yourself"](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-mysql-examples) or is that specific to that Python module?

Comment: Should `0.275` return (0, 3) or (1, 3)?

Comment: (0,3) would be more informative.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL:

```
SELECT NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_SCALE FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name= 'table' AND column_name = 'column'
```

Response in HeidiSQL

[image: Response in HeidSQL]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).